# Different behaviour between std deque/vector in MSVCC/g++/icc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++, std

I have this very simple piece of code;

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
    deque<A> my_array; // vector<A> my_array;
};

int main(void)
{
}
```

If I compile this code with both g++ and icc/icpc on linux it compiles fine, even with `-Wall` it gives no warnings. If I swap the deque to a vector the situation is the same.

I would like to build this code on windows using MSVCC (cl) but unfortunately it throws error c2027:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'A'
```

If however I change the `std::deque` to a `std::vector` it compiles fine with Visual Studio 2010.

My question is; is this behaviour to be expected for some reason? If so, why are there differences between compilers or is this a mistake with either g++/icc or MSVCC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's undefined behavior (both with `std::deque` and with `std::vector`,
so whatever an implementation does with it is fine, as far as the
standard is concerned.  You're instantiating a standard container with
an incomplete type.

When compiling with g++, `-Wall` (and in general, all options starting
with `-W`) only concern the language.  For library issues, you should be
compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` as well.  (If this causes performance
problems, you can remove the last two `-D` in optimized builds.)

Comment: "whatever an implementation does with it is fine, as far as the standard is concerned" - a conforming implementation must not fail to compile it just because it has undefined behaviour. Although of course it can give diagnostics, and putting an implementation into a conforming mode where those diagnostics are just warnings can be a little obscure.

Comment: @SteveJessop The definition of _undefined behavior_ in the standard
(§1.3.12) says explicitly "for which this International Standard imposes 
**no** requirements" (emphisis added).  And in the immediately following
note, it gives "[...] to terminating a **translation** or execution (with
the issuance of a diagnostic message)" as an example of what an
implementation might do.

Comment: @SteveJessop There are forms of undefined behavior (e.g. dereferencing a null
pointer) which are linked to the program
behavior; an implementation can only refuse to compile these if it can
prove that the undefined behavior will occur for all possible input to
the program (which is typically impossible).  That's not the case here,
however.

Comment: Ah, sorry. So I suppose that when we say, "UB can cause nasal demons", we should be saying that even running it through the compiler can cause nasal demons, unless the implementation documents that it doesn't. Since "ingoring the situation completely with unpredictable results" doesn't specify that such is only permitted at execution time but not translation time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, g++ throws an error if I specify `-D_CLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS` (well actually several)!

Comment: @SteveJessop As far as the standard is concerned.  In practice, the code will either compile and link, or it won't; most compiler authors would consider any other behavior from the compiler an error (but if the compiler core dumps, you can't complain from a standards point of view).

Answer (score 0):

Further to James Kanze's answer I searched around and found [this Dr Dobbs article](http://drdobbs.com/184403814) which explains the standard's stance on using containers with incomplete types.

Further it hints at that the reason it works with `vector`s but not `deque`s, namely the implementation. A typical vector may be something like

```
class vector<T> {
    T* buff;
    int size;
    // ... snip
};
```

which is okay with imcomplete types since we have only a pointer to `T` but `deque` could well be implemented in such a way (in VS2010) that it makes use of `T` by value thus rendering it incompatible with incomplete types.